# Modification of 'selected' attribute in amp-form

Tags: amp-html

I have a group of options inside a select in an amp-form, and would like to dynamically alter which of the options has the selected attribute set. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [amp-selector](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-selector)?

combine with amp-form + amp-bind + amp-state to achieve a form with select.

define a state under `<body>`:

```
<amp-state id="car">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "color": "black" // default option
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>
```

html part:

```
<amp-selector 
   layout="container" 
   class="category"
   name="carColor"
   on="select:AMP.setState({car: {color: event.targetOption }})" >
      <span class="category-text">Select Color:</span>
      <span option="black" class="category-btn" selected>BLACK</span>
      <span option="yellow" class="category-btn">YELLOW</span>
      <span option="red" class="category-btn">RED</span>
</amp-selector>
```

hope this helps!